# Rails Join Query with scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, search

I'm working on my first rails project, I'm stuck trying to get two of my models to work together.  Here are my models:

```
class Ecn < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :drawings, through: :revisions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :revisions, :reject_if => lambda { |attrs| attrs.all? { |key, value| value.blank? }}, :allow_destroy => true
  belongs_to :user

class Drawing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions

class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :drawing, foreign_key: :drawing_number
  belongs_to :ecn
```

What I am trying to achieve is a search for Ecns that uses the revision foreign_key :drawing_number.  When I create an Ecn, I add multiple revisions to the Ecn, which have a field for :drawing_number, which is a property of Drawings.  I have an Ecn search form, which has multiple fields to search for, one of which is :drawing_number.  I would like the query to find all Revisions that include the given :drawing_number, and find the Ecns that include those revisions.

The scope I have in my Ecn model looks like this:

```
scope :by_drawing_number, lambda { |drawing_number| Ecn.joins(:drawings).where("drawings.drawing_number LIKE ?",  "%#{drawing_number}%") unless drawing_number.nil? }
```

This scope does not throw any errors, but the search comes up with zero results.

Comment: Can you post what query is being executed?

Comment: `Revision Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "revisions".* FROM "revisions" WHERE (drawing_number LIKE '%A9999%')
  Ecn Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "ecns".* FROM "ecns" WHERE "ecns"."id" = 16 LIMIT 1
  Ecn Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "ecns".* FROM "ecns" WHERE "ecns"."id" = 23 LIMIT 1
  Ecn Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "ecns".* FROM "ecns" WHERE "ecns"."ecn_number" = 0`

Comment: This query was generated using the scope posted by mattherick below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should be possible:

```
scope :by_drawing_number, lambda { |drawing_number| Revision.where("drawing_number LIKE ?", "%#{drawing_number}%").map(&:ecn)
```

This will return a collection of Ecns.

Comment: This still doesn't load any Ecns, I posted the resulting query above in the comments.

Comment: Are you sure, that your db entries are correct? I tried out my query in one of my projects also with a has many through relation..and it works.

Comment: You may be right.  I'm not sure my models are correctly relating to one another (For example I can create a :revision with a drawing_number that does not exist in :drawings).  I'll have to do a bit more testing to see.  I was unaware of the usage of the "map" method in searching.  It looks like it should work.